# how to highlight selected tab even after page refresh without using cookie?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<ul id="ulid" class="tabs">
    <li> 
        <a href="#Tab1" id="newsdtls" class="dtls">text1</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#Tab2" id="anndtls" class="dtls">text2</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#Tab3" class="dtls">text3</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#Tab4" id="imgsdtls" class="dtls">text4</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#Tab5" id="movieMakingdtls" class="dtls">text5</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#Tab6" id="tradeInfodtls" class="dtls">text6</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In this I want to have selected tab to be in active state even after refresh. Thanks in advance.

In document ready `$("#tabs").tabs();`

I would like to get required output without using cookies. Is it possible to get by using some classes?

Comment: Why not cookies? What about localstorage?

Comment: try html5 [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-webstorage-20091222/#the-localstorage-attribute)

Comment: You can't. Or use server side script.

Comment: Iam using server side scripting

Comment: can you explain difference between localstorage and sessionstorage..what is the max limit to store I mean how many variables are being stored..?thank you..

Comment: sessionStorage persists till the session of the browser where as localstorage is similar to cookies but irrespective of browsers session the data in it persists.

Answer (score 1):

Like a @gvee says I too think that using `window.location.hash` is a best way.
See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/jmm9L/1/) link.

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:location.reload();">Reload page</a>
<div id="tabs">
<ul id="ulid" class="tabs">
    <li> 
        <a href="#Tab1" id="newsdtls" class="dtls">Text 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#Tab2" id="anndtls" class="dtls">Text 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#Tab3" class="dtls">Text 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#Tab4" id="imgsdtls" class="dtls">Text 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#Tab5" id="movieMakingdtls" class="dtls">Text 5</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a href="#Tab6" id="tradeInfodtls" class="dtls">Text 6</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="Tab1">Content 1</div>
<div id="Tab2">Content 2</div>
<div id="Tab3">Content 3</div>
<div id="Tab4">Content 4</div>
<div id="Tab5">Content 5</div>
<div id="Tab6">Content 6</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    create: function(event, ui){
        $(this).tabs({'select': $(this).find("ul").index($(this).find('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').parent())});
    },
    activate: function(event, ui){
        window.location.hash = $(ui.newTab[0]).find('a[href^="#Tab"]').attr("href");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rely on the url for this and we have great frameworks like backbone.js routing or even plugins like history.js

But without this plugins u can get the hash bang from the url and apply the active styles for the list corresponds to the it.

In order to do it HTML must be kind of like this,

```
<ul id="ulid" class="">
        <li class="">
            <a href="#tab=one" id="one" class="active">text1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab=two" id="two" class="">text2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab=three" id="three" class="">text3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab=four" id="four" class="">text4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab=five" id="five" class="">text5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab=six" id="six"  class="">text6</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Where active class css could be: `.active{background-color: red;}`

A short add on code for getting hash bang is:

```
function parseHashBangArgs(aURL) {

aURL = aURL || window.location.href;

var vars = {};
var hashes = aURL.slice(aURL.indexOf('#') + 1).split('&');

for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
   var hash = hashes[i].split('=');

   if(hash.length > 1) {
       vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
   } else {
      vars[hash[0]] = null;
   }      
}

return vars;
}
```

Then you can get run this code on page load

```
$('ul#ulid li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

var selectedTab = parseHashBangArgs(window.location.href).tab;
if(selectedTab){
    $('li a').removeClass('active');
    $('#'+selectedTab).addClass('active');
}
```

And its done!

Comment: I declared category as "text1" before document.ready globally.
getListOfDocs(id, "text1", type, subtype);
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $(".dtls").click(function() {     
     category = $(this).html();
     getList(id, category, type, subtype);//here it displays the table based on selected tab i.e.category variable});
that too class="active" have no impact on this.I just mention class attr as active in <a href>.I tried as Chaitanya said:
the o/p is : 
http://localhost:3338/extraInfo.html?2475c35886b2144d8e0354e894002819&type=movies&subtype=now#undefined
console.log(selectedTab);-->undefined

Comment: selectedTab results "undefined"  @Sai Chaitanya

Comment: I really dont have any idea what u are talking about. Can you share a fiddle of your code so that it will be clear.

Comment: when you click on **Add** Button it will take you to the separate page.let's assume you select **NNNN** tab,then it'll take you to the _page n2_.In _page n2_,there is a **Back** button.now  i want to have NNNN tab to be in active state.Before **tabs() method**,I called a method **getList(id,"NNN",type,subtype)** which gets the table regarding **NNNN**.And **$(".dtls").click(function() {
getListOfDocs(id, category, type, subtype);
}** @Sai Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

Grab the URL hash value and then find the item(s) where the `href` matches.

```
// Grab URL hash
var _hash = window.location.hash;

// Get the index of the matching tab
var tabIndex = $('#tabs a[href='+_hash+']').parent().index();

// Show the tab based on index.
$('#tabs').tabs('select', tabIndex);
```

Comment: `$(".dtls").click(function() {alert(window.location.hash);}`.But it results empty alert.@gvee

Answer (score 0):

Try out [HTML5 History API](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-history-api-syntax/) or use location.hash for storing the selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
       in
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    active = $(this).attr('id');
                    //contains the id of the selected tab
                    $.cookie('active', active);
                    //place that id in cookie
                })
                $(window).load(function() {//after the page refresh
                    var a = $.cookie('active');
                    //get the value from cookie
                    $('#' + a).trigger('click');
                    //Earlier it doesn/t display the list corresponding to the selected tab after page refresh because it doesn't detect click event.So,generate a click event using "trigger".It's working fine now.Thankyou for all who tried for my code
                });
```